# Android Studio Can't Connect to Internet/Download SDK on Windows 11

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, proxy, windows-11

Really frustrating issue: i'm trying to install and run Android Studio on Windows 11, but every time I open it I get a message that some broken proxy setting is preventing the Android SDK from being downloaded. I'm not using a proxy at all as far as I know.

I've read lots of posts explaining that it's a Windows Firewall issue, but nothing I've tried has worked. What I've tried so far:

- Reinstalled Android Studio
- Added Android Studio inbound & outbound exceptions to Windows Firewall
- Disabled Windows Firewall entirely
- Tried installing on different users on same Machine (same error)
- Installed Electric Eel Beta version of Android Studio (instead of stable channel's Dolphin, same error)
- Flushed DNS cache on my PC
- Closing the first run wizard and trying to manually download the SDK from SDK Manager in Android Studio (always "Unavailable")

Nothing has worked. I see this user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877973/android-studio-sdk-installation-issue-in-windows-11) faced my exact issue and they said they were able to fix it by "relaxing restrictions with Windows Firewall". I'm not sure what that means beyond what I've already tried.

As far as I know I'm not actively connecting to the internet on my machine via any Proxies or VPNs. Maybe my torrenting software changed settings somewhere? It's just strange because I've never had this issue before, even with torrenting software running/installed.

What should I do to get Android Studio to correctly download the Android SDK?

[image: First time run always complains about proxy settings (what proxy??)][image: Auto proxy settings don't work, fail to connect to https://cnn.com]
[image: SDK always shows as "Unavailable"]
[image: SDK Manager shows strange error abut filesystem root. Editing does nothing (leads to SDK showing as "Unavailable" for download)]

Comment: Try changing it to  "no proxy". If it still doesn't work, but you can confirm that other apps can access internet on the same machine, the it would have to be a router/firewall issue

Comment: @user496854 The error still persists with "no proxy". Other apps access the internet fine on this machine, its just Android Studio that seems problematic. What can I do to try to resolve the issue? Even when I disable Windows Defender (the firewall) the issue still persists.

Comment: Well, you first have to figure out where the problem actually lies. At this point, my guess is that either your router or your ISP is somehow blocking that connection. So, the first thing you would have to do is set up another machine on the same network, install Android studio there, and see if it has any problems. You can also try to connect your current PC to a totally different network (I know it's not very convenient, but that's really the only way you're going to find out if it's a problem with your network or the problem with your PC)

Comment: @user496854 I just tried on a different network and the issue remains. So, at this point, we can confirm that the issue isn't the network, but my machine. What other steps can I take to further diagnose? Neither disabling Windows defender nor installing Android Studio on a different profile fixed the issue.

Comment: the only other thing you can try is the usual stuff to reset the windows network: reset network stack, flush your DNS cache, and make sure that your network adapter is set to use DHCP instead of any hardcoded settings. If that doesn't work, try manually setting the DNS server to either Google (8.8.8.8) or CloudFlare (1.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all kinds of network resets, connecting to alternative networks, etc., I was able to fix the issue by resetting Windows to factory settings.

After that, I downloaded and installed Android Studio and it was able to automatically downloaded the SDK during the first-run with no issues.